# Debug mysql - The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I am trying to open(and debug) mysql source in Visual studio 15. I have build the source. But when I open innobase project in it for debugging it showed the above error.

I have tried following thing:

1. Ensure debug configuration, debug flag, and full debug info are set on all assemblies.
2. Disable the "Just My Code" option in the Debug/General settings.
3. Couldn't find obj or bin folder to delete them. However tried deleting all the .obj files but didn't worked.
4. Ensured mysql.exe and mysql.pdb match using chkMatch tool.
5. Have added right path to load symbols.
6. Opening project in debug mode.
7. tried changing debug information format.

currently, for all the modules loaded(including mysql.exe) the symbol status is 'symbol loaded'. But still the break point doesn't work. 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that given `.cc` file is correct, and is part of one of loaded DLLs?

Comment: The given .cc file is correct acc. to me. And how to check it is part of one of loaded DLLs.

Comment: Change the source file to cause compiler error. If there is no compiler error, this file is not part. If there is compiler error, revert and see which DLL gets updated.

Comment: You may try to put `DebugBreak();` explicitly.

Comment: There was a compiler error but none of the DLL got updated.

Comment: The DLL is not the one you are expecting. See the output window to find which/where the DLL is getting generated.

Comment: In the output window, there is no mention of any DLL in the output generated from build. And in the output generated from debug all the DLL present in the module section are loaded.

Comment: Then you need to rebuild and see, or delete appropriate DLL you are expecting to have correct symbol, then do a normal build. You must find out which DLL is being referred.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know which/where is the DLL which is expected to have correct symbol. I thought symbol file for mysql.exe is enough.

Comment: The DLL/EXE where this file exist: `ha_innodb.cc`. Merely putting PDB of EXE won't help. Each DLL should have been built with `/DEBUG` linker flag

Comment: I checked, there is no DLL or EXE where this file exist. :(

Comment: You didn't get it clearly, I think. I mean if you build a program having `a.cpp` file, for a DLL or EXE - `a.cpp` is referred by DLL/EXE. They may very well exist in different folders. It's task of compiler/linker to put symbol/debugging information in EXE/DLL about all source files.

Comment: @Ajay It turns out project was not build properly. It is still not. Currently getting this error: ' MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.' and 'LNK1181 Fatal error cannot open input file 'sql.lib'. Please help.